# Sequelize query - is it possible to alias field in included (inner join) model

Tags: join, sequelize.js, field, alias

Can't seem to find an answer to this (if there is one).

So I have 2 sequelize models. The association is working fine but I wish to alias a field from the outer model on which the inner is being performed.

When I performed this query: -

```
ModelOne.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', ['attribute2', 'attribute2Alias'],],
    include: [{
        model: ModelTwo,
        required: true,
        attributes: [
            ['attribute1', 'attribute1Alias']
        ],
    }],
})
```

I get back this: -

```
items: [{
    id: 1,
    attribute2Alias: 'value',
    'ModelTwoTableName.attribute1Alias': 'value'
}]
```

I understand that I could use .map on the the returned rows but is there any way to avoid this by performing an alias directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It only happens** when you **use 'raw:true'** in your query ,

I think the output you are showing is with `raw:true` , **remove that** and then run your query again

Comment: Thanks. Is there any option to run the query with the alias and return only an array of the data or and I looking at having to .map() the results?

Comment: it appears to make no difference setting this to true or false. I still get back `[Table2].Column: List` rather than `Column: List`. I don't want a list either but that is a separate issue

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same shortcoming and found the solution. You could refer to the outer column attribute from the top level attributes list. Then use `sequelize.col()` together with the table name. This requires `raw:true` otherwise sequelize will complain. The outer attributes list could be left empty. Like this:

```
ModelOne.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', ['attribute2', 'attribute2Alias'], [sequelize.col('table2.attribute1'), 'attribute1Alias']],
    include: [{
        model: ModelTwo,
        required: true,
        attributes: [],
    }],
    raw: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In stable 6.0 version of Sequelize the following works out:

```
ModelOne.findAll({
...
include: {association: 'modeltwos', attributes: []}
})
```

Note: 'modeltwos' is alias of ModelTwo, set in ModelOne model:

```
static associate({ ModelTwo }) {
      // define association here
      models.ModelOne.hasMany(ModelTwo, { as: 'modeltwos' }); 
}
```